# how to make two log files using logging module in python?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

Hello folks!

```
 #this is values from xml file.
    clientID = logObject['meta']['clientID']
    authToken = logObject['meta']['authToken']
    logType = logObject['logType']

    FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(logType)s %(process)d %(user)-8s %(message)s'
    d = {'logType': logType ,'user': getpass.getuser()}
    #line creating two log files(access.log and error.log) 
    logging.basicConfig(filename = 'access.log', filemode = 'w', format=FORMAT)
    logging.basicConfig(filename = 'error.log', filemode = 'w', format=FORMAT)

    if(clientID == ""):
        # logger = setup_logger('first_logger', 'access.log',logType)
        logger.warning('Please Enter clientID', extra=d)
```

This is my sample code. 
 what i need is to create two files which i have mentioned. but problem is it only creates single file everytime and messages goes to that file only.
    So i want that if i mention logger.error("msg") or logger.warning("msg") then it should go to that log file.

Answer (score 0):

When you use just `logging` you actually use single root logger created during `import logging`. You may use it with several handlers. For example:

```
# 1. logging to file
filename = (
    'log_file{}.log'
    .format(
        dt.datetime.today().strftime("_date_%Y-%m-%d_time_%H-%M-%S")))
# path to log folder.
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'logs')
# create log folder if it does not exist.
if not os.path.isdir(path):
    os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
to_file = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(path, filename))
to_file.addFilter(lambda x: x.levelno in [20, 40])

# 2. logging to console
to_console = logging.StreamHandler()
to_console.addFilter(lambda x: x.levelno in [20, 21, 40])

# 3. root logger configuration
logging.basicConfig(
    level=10,
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    format='[%(asctime)s]:%(threadName)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s',
    handlers=[to_console, to_file])
```

If you want to log into 2 files then just create 2 handlers `logging.FileHandler(...)`, register them, and use newly configured root logger as usual:

```
logging.info('Some info')
```

Another option is to create 2 loggers. Usually you need to do so if you want to separate several sources of log messages.

Comment: Where do i put logging.info, logging.warning message?Can you tell me how to do it with two loggers? cos i had tried but didn't work.

Comment: @DHARMIKSONI Using a single root logger is easier. You don't have to create it. Only to configure. Just use `logging.message_type('message')` where you need. If you want 2 loggers then (1) create them like `logger_1 = looging.getLogger(...)`, (2) add handlers like `logger_1.addHandler(...)`, (3) use them like `logger_1.message_type('message')`. There is a good HowTo about logging in Python https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html